# Android track device orientation when orientation is locked

Tags: android

I have an activity with locked orientation

```
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

How i can know when user change device orientation?
*Maybe question is too unclear, so i try explain what i want in result.*

> I want to know when user rotate phone AND AFTER THAT rotate layout and other views with my own animation.

I think i can use SensorManager, but maybe exist more elegant way?

Comment: yes there might be a way... w8 for my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Well I have used The `OnScreenChangetListener()` once. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationListener.html#onOrientationChanged(int)). It tells everything. Just execute your animation code in the Method. It might work.
If the Above method doesn't work, there is a Method below the `OnScreenChangetListener()` method in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationListener.html#onOrientationChanged(int)). it will work for sure.

Comment: Well let guess if I m right. You want to know if the screen position is landscape then u want to change the Screen Orientation With Animation right???

Comment: No, i need a callback portrait->landscape and landscape->portrait. This method not called when activity orientation locked.

Comment: `This class was deprecated in API level 3.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83692/discussion-between-syed-ali-naqi-and-ssh).